# Github Desktop: Not able to publish

Tags: github, github-desktop

I have a project which I want to upload to GitHub. I have used Github Desktop to create a local repository and I am able to commit files to it. But once I try to publish it, the publish icon just fades and won't allow me to do it. I have checked my settings in `Settings->Options` and they are correct.

Comment: Does your local repo has a remote url? (type `git remote -v`, if empty `git remote add origin https://github.com/<user>/<an_empty_repo>`)

Comment: To do what @VonC suggested in GitHub Desktop, go to `Settings->Repository settings->Remote`

Comment: @VonC No. The local repo does not have a remote url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the local repo has no remote url, you need to add one, referencing a remote empty repo that you own (on GitHub for instance):

```
cd /path/to/repo
git remote add origin https://github.com/<user>/<an_empty_repo>
```

Or, in GitHub Desktop:

```
Settings->Repository settings->Remote
```

Then you will be able to publish.